# Is there a statistical test i can perform to see if age is correlated to a binary outcome?

Tags: correlation

I am doing a study on tympanoplasty, a procedure to close one's eardrum. I would like to see if there is any correlation between a positive outcome (a.k.a. a closed typmanic membrane) and age. My outome is binary (open or closed tympanic membrane) and age is nominal. Is there a test that I can perform?

Comment: I guess that age is ordinal...isn't it?

Comment: Hi, Elise. A fellow physician, here. So take it with a pinch of salt, but it sounds like you'd be happy with a binomial logistic regression, as pointed out below. Are you using [R]? What statistical package are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a binomial logistic regression.
In matlab:
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html